# asp.netmvc web helpers chart themeing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a currently silverlight graph that needs to be changed to a image graph

I can get the columns and data in there  fine 
[image]

however I cannot seem to figure out how to colorize the bars as below (right now I use the max 20% values as red   anything between 20% and 80% of max is yellow and the low 20% as green)

[image]

Comment: You probably need to show the code you use to convert the silverlight graph into an image so that we can point out any areas where you can add your coloring code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It apparently cannot be done the themes  are hardcoded (it seems)

```
 public const string Blue = "<Chart BackColor=\"#D3DFF0\" BackGradientStyle=\"TopBottom\" BackSecondaryColor=\"White\" BorderColor=\"26, 59, 105\" BorderlineDashStyle=\"Solid\" BorderWidth=\"2\" Palette=\"BrightPastel\">\r\n    <ChartAreas>\r\n        <ChartArea Name=\"Default\" _Template_=\"All\" BackColor=\"64, 165, 191, 228\" BackGradientStyle=\"TopBottom\" BackSecondaryColor=\"White\" BorderColor=\"64, 64, 64, 64\" BorderDashStyle=\"Solid\" ShadowColor=\"Transparent\" /> \r\n    </ChartAreas>\r\n    <Legends>\r\n        <Legend _Template_=\"All\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" Font=\"Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold\" IsTextAutoFit=\"False\" /> \r\n    </Legends>\r\n    <BorderSkin SkinStyle=\"Emboss\" /> \r\n  </Chart>";
```

Which would mean having separate series for separate colors.

It will however be possible once Microsoft releases MVC 3 Source code